# “out of sorts” vs “down in the dumps”

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms **'out of sorts'** and **'down in the dumps'**? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

- out of sorts : *in an unhappy mood*
- down in the dumps : *unhappy*

Comment: Other dictionaries suggest _mildly unwell_ (or similar) for _out of sorts_, which is how I've always thought of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down%20in%20the%20dumps%2Cout%20of%20sorts&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) hows, **out of sorts** is a lot more common.

The two expressions certainly have a large overlap, but in my opinion, there is a difference of degree between the two. **Out of sorts** means slightly unhappy, probably temporarily- maybe reflecting your mood today. **Down in the dumps** suggests a rather more serious an long-term problem.